# JOIN 5 Database in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have 5 Database, Let say their name is `A` `B` `C` `D` `E`

All database have the same table / structure / field

I want to get result from 5 database using table `SMSOutgoing` and the field is `uid`

It look like this :

```
SELECT * OR JOIN 5 database A B C D E F
FROM `table` SMSOutgoing
WHERE uid = 1
```

Not all the database have uid=1, it need to display which database have the result

I run SMS Gateway, each phone / 1 number using 1 database, thats why there is so many different database.

I spent hours to solve it but always error, I think i follow the wrong guide (JOIN multiple table in 1 database)

I'm Lost, please Help and Thank You

Comment: What do you want your output to be? Do you need to list `Database B` for example in the result set indicating which DB held the result?

Comment: I want the output * (All the Field) The DB held the result is A

Comment: If you need to do this frequently with the same tables, you might want to create a union table. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/merge-storage-engine.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to list the databases out that contain uid = 1 in the SMSOutgoing table.  If so, you should be able to use `UNION`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'DatabaseA' WhichDb
FROM DatabaseA.SMSOutgoing 
WHERE uid = 1
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT 'DatabaseB' WhichDb
FROM DatabaseB.SMSOutgoing 
WHERE uid = 1
UNION
...
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT 'DatabaseF' WhichDb
FROM DatabaseF.SMSOutgoing 
WHERE uid = 1
```

I used `DISTINCT` in case you could have multiple uid in the same table -- that may be unnecessary.

*EDIT: From your comments, it sounds like you just want the results:*

```
SELECT *
FROM DatabaseA.SMSOutgoing 
WHERE uid = 1
UNION
SELECT *
FROM DatabaseB.SMSOutgoing 
WHERE uid = 1
UNION
...
UNION
SELECT *
FROM DatabaseF.SMSOutgoing 
WHERE uid = 1
```

You may need to use `UNION ALL` if you might have duplicates...

Comment: Thank You, I have 1 more question, I have 1 more database but with different table and field but the same uid=1, database name 'F', table 'SMSOUT' how to include it at the query?

Comment: @LucyAmaliaLusiana -- you can still UNION it in your query, but the UNION must return the same number of columns.  So instead of specifying SELECT *, use SELECT uid, otherfield... FROM... If the fields don't match up, you can't include in a single query.  Best of luck!

Comment: Thank You, I will keep try it until it work, thank you for explaining to me to use UNION